# Printing two reverse hollow rectangles then printing two diagonals inside them

Tags: c++

I am trying to write code for constructing two hollow rectangles. The hollow rectangles have got two diagonals drawn until half. Making it divided into two right angle triangles and one other triangle in middle. One of them would inverse on the downwards. It would look like:

```
********************
*       *  *       *
*      *    *      *
*     *      *     *
*    *        *    *
*   *          *   *
*  *            *  *
* *              * *
**                **
********************

********************
**                **
* *              * *
*  *            *  *
*   *          *   *
*    *        *    *
*     *      *     *
*      *    *      *
*       *  *       *
********************
```

Can someone help me with code for this? Width and Length are entered by the
user for the image above the *length is 10* and the *width is 20*.

I am able to construct the hollow rectangles; they aren't a main problem, the problem comes when I want to print the diagonals. Tried various conditions but none of them are working.

Comment: You can insert images directly in your question. Which makes me/us feel more comfortable than clicking some unknowkn link. If it's just terminal output it would still be easier to copy-paste an example of such a pattern as text. Also please show us what you already tried.

Comment: I am new on stack overflow so don't know much :) , I tried adding that but it says the minimum requirement is 10 points or something. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that exploits the vertical symmetry. `full_j` goes from top to bottom, `i` goes from left to right. The border is easy. For the up diagonal, observe that `i` and `j` are always equal, starting at 1,1. For the down diagonal, observe that `i+j` is a constant, say `c`, and that it passes `i,j` = `length,1`, therefore `c = length+1`.

```
void print_diagonals_in_rectangles(int width, int length)
{
    int i, j, full_j;
    for (full_j = -width; full_j <= width; ++full_j)
    {
        j = full_j;
        if (j < 0)
            j = -j;  // abs(full_j)
        for (i = 1; i <= length; ++i)
        {
            if (j == 0)
                printf(" ");  // empty in the center
            else if (j == 1 || j == width || i == 1 || i == length  // the borders
                    || i + j == length + 1 || i == j)  // the diagonals
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");  // all the rest empty
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Here is what it prints for 10, 20:

```
********************
*       *  *       *
*      *    *      *
*     *      *     *
*    *        *    *
*   *          *   *
*  *            *  *
* *              * *
**                **
********************

********************
**                **
* *              * *
*  *            *  *
*   *          *   *
*    *        *    *
*     *      *     *
*      *    *      *
*       *  *       *
********************
```

And for 7, 7:

```
*******
**   **
* * * *
*  *  *
* * * *
**   **
*******

*******
**   **
* * * *
*  *  *
* * * *
**   **
*******
```

Edit: Removed a version that used the [ternary operator ( ... ? ... : ...)](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/).

Comment: What output does it give on width = 15 and length = 30 ? Does it start from the corners or from inside? The diagnols must be starting from corners from below.

Comment: Did you try to run the code? Did you try to read the code?

Comment: Sorry I was sleepy at that moment tried it runs greatly , seems quite complex for new beginners though. I solved it in another way but thanks a lot for the conditions <3  .(i + j == length + 1) || (i == j) this helped a lot.

Comment: Does it look less complex without the ternary operator?